# Why is my react function returning [object,object]

Tags: reactjs

I have a function in my Numbers component that should return the state however it returns [object,object] I cant see what i've done wrong?
I've written a function in Numbers, that returns another function in my apps component!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Numbers from './Numbers'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super()
    this.state={
      calcValue:0
    }
  }

  takeValue = (n) => {
    alert(n)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Numbers submit={(n) => this.takeValue(n)} numberValue={1}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Number component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

class Numbers extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state={
      numberValue:6
    }
  }

  submit = (n) => {
    this.props.takeValue(this.state.numberValue)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button value={this.state.numberValue} onClick={this.props.submit}>
          {this.props.numberValue}
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Completed.propTypes={
// test:propTypes.string.isRequired

export default Numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not understanding concept of passing the props. you need to differentiate what you are passing into child component and how you want to call the parent from child.

Change

```
onClick={this.props.submit}
```

to

```
 onClick={this.submit}
```

and

```
 submit=(n) => {    
       this.props.takeValue(this.state.numberValue)    
    }
```

to

```
  submit = (n) => {
    this.props.submit(this.state.numberValue)
  }
```

`onClick={this.props.submit}` will call parent component not the child one

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gsnh1w)

Comment: Thanks Yes I have seen my mistakes. I am new to React.

Comment: @Lee yes it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have found my error! Should be `this.submit` not `this.props.submit`
Also  I needed to call the `takeValue` function

Thanks

Comment: yep. I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dobewq

Comment: This section is reserved for answers, you can thank @Just code by accepting his answer